# Docker Redis CLI Timeout

Tags: redis, docker

I have a Redis Service running inside a docker container but when connecting to it the cursor is not returned.

When using redis-cli the terminal just hangs with issuing commands, I hope someone can point out where I'm going wrong.

Instead of seeing regular redis-cli output like:

```
% redis-cli
redis 127.0.0.1:6379> set docker awesome
OK
redis 127.0.0.1:6379> get docker
"awesome"
redis 127.0.0.1:6379>
```

This is what I am seeing:

```
% redis-cli -p 49156
redis 127.0.0.1:49156> set docker awesome
```

There's no "OK" and the terminal just hangs until I Ctrl-C it.

I'm following the docker.io instructions from http://docs.docker.io/en/latest/examples/running_redis_service/

Here's my Dockerfile:

```
FROM        ubuntu:12.10
RUN         apt-get update
RUN         apt-get -y install redis-server
EXPOSE      6379
ENTRYPOINT  ["/usr/bin/redis-server"]
```

I build the image with:

```
sudo docker build -t rudijs/redis .
```

I run an instance of the image with:

```
sudo docker run -d -p 6379 -name redis rudijs/redis

% sudo docker ps                             
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                 COMMAND                CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                     NAMES
3888fa49b605        rudijs/redis:latest   /usr/bin/redis-serve   5 seconds ago       Up 4 seconds        0.0.0.0:49156->6379/tcp   redis
```

The exposed container redis port is at:

```
% sudo docker port redis 6379
0.0.0.0:49156

% redis-cli -p 49156
redis 127.0.0.1:49156> set docker awesome
```

I've tried tinkering with different port bindings from the container to the host but the result is always the same - cli hang.

Issuing command like "help" seem to work fine

```
% redis-cli -p 49156
redis 127.0.0.1:49156> help
redis-cli 2.2.12
Type: "help @<group>" to get a list of commands in <group>
      "help <command>" for help on <command>
      "help <tab>" to get a list of possible help topics
      "quit" to exit
redis 127.0.0.1:49156>
```

If I just let it sit I get a timeout:

```
% redis-cli -p 49156
redis 127.0.0.1:49156> set docker awesome
Error: Connection reset by peer
(248.52s)
redis 127.0.0.1:49156>
```

Any advice or tips with this problem much appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The fix for this was Firehol (iptables) rules were needed:

```
interface docker0 interface1 src "172.17.0.0/16" dst 172.17.42.1
    server all accept
    client all accept
```